# Async/wait does not work with middleware nodejs

Tags: node.js, session, async-await, middleware, es6-promise

I have create a middleware to create a session for every login with token and userId parameter, and it is based on loopback framework.

- It first check if the session with same userID and tokenID exist then do not create new session escape this phase else create session.

Here is my code :

```
module.exports = async function(req, res, next) {
  try {

    let jobUser = req.app.models.JobsUser;

    var session = req.app.models.userSession;
    var sessionRequest = req.app.models.UserSessionRequest;
    var ip = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
    let logDetails = {
      lastActivity: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date(),
      ip: ip,
      browser: req.useragent.browser,
      browserVersion: req.useragent.version,
      platform: req.useragent.platform,
      operatingSystem: req.useragent.os,
      block: false,
      blockBy: "",
    };
    /** Create session after login */
    await jobUser.afterRemote('login', async(context, user, next) => {


      /** Check if already a session exist for this user.*/
      let newSession = session.find({ where: { userId: user.userId, token: user.id } }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Records already exist');
          next(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log('AccessToken: ' + result.length);
        console.log('AccessToken: ' + user.id);
        console.log('Session does not exist');
        if (result.length === 0) {
          let uer = { toke: user.id, userId: user.userId, createdAt: user.created };
          let rec = {...logDetails, ...uer };
          session.create(rec, (err, result) => {
            next();
            return;
          });
        }
      });
    });

    if (req.accessToken === null) return next();

    let logs = {...logDetails, userId: req.accessToken.userId, token: req.accessToken.id, createdAt: req.accessToken.created }
      /** Update session for every other request */
    let result = await session.updateAll({ userId: req.accessToken.userId, token: req.accessToken.id }, logs);
    var requestDetails = {
      sessionId: result.id,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date(),
      route: req.headers.referer,
      method: req.method,
      browser: req.useragent.browser,
      platform: req.useragent.platform,
      operatingSystem: req.useragent.os
    };
    if (result) {
      await sessionRequest.create(requestDetails);
    }

    /** Close session after logout */
    jobUser.afterRemote('logout', (context, User, next) => {
      session.updateAll({ userId: req.accessToken.userId, token: req.accessToken.id }, { closedAt: new Date() });
      next();
      return;
    });

    next();
    return;
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
    return;
  }
};
```

Output:

[image]

For this purpose I have used **async/await** to do not create multiple session at the same time.

I don't know either I am going wrong way, or the **async/wait** does not work properly with middleware.

Your advice would be appreciate it.

Note : Its API based loopback and angular 4

Comment: You're mixing promises with callbacks, which is likely causing problems.

Comment: So how can I solve that?

Comment: Use only of Promise